# Locking elements in contenteditable="true" div

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a contenteditable div that's used for user input, when a button is clicked it shows options to replace certain words. First it strips away all html and creates span elements where a word can be replaced. The mark up of these words is different and I face some problems.

1. When clicking directly before or after a span and typing text the text will have the same markup as the span. It's very hard to add words on a line that only has the span. I was thinking of solving this by padding the spans with `&nbsp;` but it looks kind of strange.
2. User can click in the span and change it, I would rather have the user click on the span and choose a replace or ignore option before changing it. In other words it needs to be locked. I was thinking of doing this by capturig keyup and if it comes from a span then e.preventDefault() on it but it's a bit of a pain to program it.

So my questions are:

Is there an easy way of locking a span element in a contenteditable that doesn't involve capturing key up and preventDefault (have not tried yet and not even sure if it'll work)?

When clicking or moving the cursor directly next to a span and typing text it'll be part of the span, is there a way to not have it be part of the span? Padding the span with `&nbsp;` might work but it looks strange when the span is the first word on the line. To illustrate this I've posted an example html file below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
<title>Example</title>
</head>
 <body>
   <div contenteditable="true"></div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0]
      .innerHTML="<span style='color:green'>hello</span>"
   </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for locking elements in the contenteditable div; I am using spans that need to be locked and they do not trigger keydown events so have set the event on the div and check through range if it's a locked element.

I am using google closure library so getting the range is simple:

```
goog.events.listen(document.getElementById("userInput"),//userInput= contenteditable div
   [goog.events.EventType.KEYDOWN,
    goog.events.EventType.PASTE],
   function(e){
       if(32<e.keyCode&&e.keyCode<41){//page up,down,home,end and arrow
           return;
       }
       var el=goog.dom.Range.createFromWindow()
         .getContainerElement();
       if(el.className.indexOf("locked")!==-1){
           e.preventDefault();
       }
});
```

I'll look into padding the locked span with **&nbsp;** if no whitespace exist before or after the element and post it here once I get the solution.

Ended up padding the spans without checking since the extra whitespace will be removed later anyway. Looks kind of funny but it's better then not being able to add text.

Answer (score 2):

Mark the span inside your editable container contenteditable="false". It'll solve both problems at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This doesn't work in IE9, I can click in the span and change it. In FF I can press control+a and then delete the whole content, not a big deal for my implementation but maybe someone else would not like to see the locked content removed like that.