# Simultaneously moving element within text input (textarea or contentEditable div)

Tags: javascript, html, dom, textarea, contenteditable

The task is to implement an input which have a submit element right after the text end and submit element can move when user is typing or inserting text in the input (user can't delete this element or cange it, only click to submit text and also user can't type text after it). First implementation that I tried dealed with *input* event of *textarea*, counting absolute submit element position depending on input text length. It seems that this is not a good solution due to troubles with this event, especially then any key is pressed for a long time (input event simply fires just once). So I'm looking for solution with *contenteditable*. The problem explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16464564/locking-elements-in-contenteditable-true-div) is similar to mine in some way but still I can't figure out how to implement this in my case.

Comment: Why not use key events as well as the `input` event?

Comment: Well, as I mentioned above, this was my first solution. the problem is that all these events are not fired if we, for example, press any key for a long time. Side effects: the position of submit element is not adjusted

Comment: You should get at least one of `keydown` and `keypress` firing for auto-repeated keypresses in most browsers. See http://unixpapa.com/js/testkey.html.

Comment: Thank you, Tim. Yes, indeed you are right. It was an error in my own code. Still there were problems with smooth submit element movement while typing and its positioning (it also should behave like text area), so I implemented this using contenteditable and contenteditable='false' for submit element. Everything works fine, besides some corner cases: when I press del just before submit element it is deleted also I can start typing after it. Now I'm trying to solve this problems with your rangy lib. Is there any good solution you can suggest?